# Does Apple push updates that require a restart within a set timeframe?

Tags: macos, security, software-update, notifications

Just got this notification on my MacBook Pro running OS 10.12.6.

[image]

It reads:

> macOS updates have been installed.  This computer will restart in 60 minutes. Please save anything you are working on and log out by choosing Log Out from the bottom of the Apple menu.

Four things about it strike me as un-Apple-like:

1. The tone
2. The unfamiliar, unnecessary icon
3. Forcing me to restart instead of providing a choice
4. Non-conformity with Notification Center notifications pushed by the App Store

This raises three questions:

- Does Apple push updates that require a restart within a set
  timeframe?

  - If so, since when, and why?
  - If not, should I be suspicious of this notification?

Comment: And sure enough, my computer restarted without my permission. Good thing I wasn’t giving a presentation!

Comment: Updates to kernel (and kernel extensions which can’t be reloaded safely) require a reboot. 60 minutes is generous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not Apple. If macOS has not been able to install updates without interruption, Apple software updates will show in Notification Center and will *not* force you to update.

The message in your question is from an MDM provider your organisation has installed on your computer, which in this case is [JAMF](https://www.jamf.com). You should contact your organisation if you have any queries about the actions taken on the computer.

Comment: Aha! So the hacker I suspected is actually the _owner_ of my computer.